# Accessing JavaScript object with keys that looks like a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have a javascript object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    "1": {
        "status": "online",
        "friends": "4,6,9,12,26,38,40,41,42,51,52,59,183",
        "ws": {}
    },
    "6": { "status": "online", "friends": "1,9", "ws": {} }
}
```

I also have a variable defined like this:

```
var id = 1;
```

I'm trying to access the object with this id like this:

```
obj[id]
```

The result is `undefined`. Why?

I also tried:

```
obj[id.toString()]
obj[String(id)]
```

both results in `undefined`.

Why?

This is in NodeJS if that is relevant.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/L5nssztd/

Comment: No, that would work. Please do `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj), id, obj[i])` and post the results.

Comment: Is obj itself defined? Where do you define obj?

Comment: Works fine in NodeJS too.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of async task on obj ? If that is the case you might get this issue when you access obj in sync way .